# Colour of Mouse Pointer

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

My browser is IE 9.

Is there any way to change the Mouse Pointer colour inside the Textbox to white.I want to place the code in the text changed event of the textbox
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 input[type="text"]:focus /*Or your css selector*/
 {
   cursor:none;
 }
```

Comment: I want to change the colour of cursor on click of the textbox.

Comment: You can use the `:active` or the `:focus` selector. You can also set an onclick event in js and change the cursor there.